# How do you use the Contentful Middleman preview API in different build environment?

Tags: ruby, middleman, contentful

Here's what I'm trying to achieve in principle, which obviously doesn't work since the contentful data needs to be retrieved before the build:

```
# Build command
bundle exec middleman contentful && bundle exec middleman build -e <ENV>
```

```rb
# config.rb

configure :prod do
  set :build_dir, 'build/prod'
  set :ENV, 'prod'

  activate :contentful do |f|
    f.space         = { hs: 'SPACE' }
    f.access_token  = 'TOKEN'
    f.cda_query     = { include: 2 }
    f.all_entries   = true
    f.content_types = { #... }
  end
end

configure :testSite do
  set :build_dir, 'build/test-site'
  set :ENV, 'test'

  activate :contentful do |f|
    use_preview_api = true
    #...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use environment variables to switch on that.

```
# Build command
CONTENTFUL_ENV=<env> bundle exec middleman contentful && bundle exec middleman build -e <env>


# config.rb
access_token = nil
use_preview = false
case ENV['CONTENTFUL_ENV']
when 'prod'
  access_token = ENV['CONTENTFUL_PROD_TOKEN']
when 'testSite'
  access_token = ENV['CONTENTFUL_TEST_TOKEN']
  use_preview = true
end

activate :contentful do |f|
  f.space = {space_alias: ENV['CONTENTFUL_SPACE']}
  f.use_preview_api = use_preview
  f.access_token = access_token
  # ...
end
```

This way you can have multiple environments working together

Comment: This works as explained and is exactly what I was looking for - thank you.

Comment: Glad it was what you were looking for! Cheers

Comment: @DavidLitvak so you're setting the space and token id' in the .htaccess?

Comment: @AndreZimpel Those are environment variables on your development/production build environment. This are not required once built to be served. If you use something like CircleCI or Netlify to do your builds, these are things that can be easily configured on their settings. If you're using your own machine, then you can take a look on how to set up environment variables here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-unix/